# Need Some Suggestion For A Regex

Tags: c#, regex, unicode

Hi guys I Need Some Help With A Regex:
I Need A Regex:
1. that accepts all type of characters like ą or Э or Ǿ or Я ...
2. which the number of characters is between 3 and 15
3. doesn't contain special characters

Comment: "all types" but not "special"? What do you mean?

Comment: in future use this [site](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to test out regex expressions,I learnt all I need to know from that site!

Comment: by special do you mean control characters

Comment: some special word like this ĢąΜЭ ǾVЭЯ

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to match 3 to 15 Unicode letters. For that, you can use

```
new Regex(@"^\p{L}{3,15}$")
```

If you also want to allow spaces, you can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
new Regex(@"^[\p{L} ]{3,15}$")
```

Comment: but that cant contain some special word like ĢąΜЭ ǾVЭЯ or thing like that

Comment: @FirasNajar `\p{L}` supports all unicode `letters`..it would also match above text which are unicode letters

Comment: it doesn't support spaces ! can you edit it 
need to write more then 1 word

Comment: @Corak: You should remove the `|`, it doesn't mean "or" within a character class.